# Build.bat error code 6 in the Unreal Engine 5

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, unreal-engine5

I use Unreal Engine 5.1.1 with Visual Studio 2022 and all the time I compile a code, even a script from a template project, or a new, just created empty script - I get an error in Visual Studio:

```
Error   MSB3073 The command ""C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat" MyProjectEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:\Users\lord_\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject\MyProject.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6
```

I haven't tried anything so far, besides creating a new Unreal project, since I am a very noob and just getting familiarised with the engine and C++

Comment: The best way to know what error code 6 means would be to look at the build.bat file and see under what situations it returns that code.

Comment: Terminology side note: C++ is a compiled language. C++ source files are *not* "scripts".

Answer (score 2):

Don't open unreal engine with the desktop icon. Load the visual studio 2022 project which the engine build by default and then ctrl+f5 to build the solution. Then unreal engine will boot automatically. This error comes when unreal engine 5 is already opened in the background with visual studio. I guess this code is simply made to boot the engine. I wasted a lot of time on this to figure out the solution, and it was this silly lol.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution: either close the editor before compiling or disable Live Coding in the Editor Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. There are requirements in Visual Studio to work with Unreal. But also make sure to have the Visual Studio integration Tool installed from Epic Games.